# How to calculate users' reputation

Tags: algorithms

I have a website that people upload their photos there, I am looking for a formula to calculate my user's reputation. Here are entities I have:

A = **Total number of followers**

B = **Total number of followings**

C = **Total number of uploaded photo**

D = **Total stars for each photo**

E = There is an option on the website that each user can copy other user photos, it means that user liked that photo a lot, and wanted to have it on his profile too. So, **we have Total number of copies each photo has** *(it's usually fewer than the number of stars each photo has)*

F = **User total stars for all his photos *(sum of stars)***

G = **User total number of copies of his photos *(sum of Copies)***

We need a formula that can calculate a user reputation and their real value on the website, for example, there are users who are following 100,000 other users and have 25,000 followers, but that's not very valuable *(because we send notification, and that's why they get more followers)* there are users who are following just 10 people but have around 25,000 followers.

For stars too, we have photos that got 100,000 stars and 2,000 copies. Copies are more valuable than stars.

We want to sort out users by their reputation, and also it's helpful for better recommendations.

What I was thinking about wat something like the formula below:

```
Reputation = Round((A/B) / ​3​ + (F​ ​/​ ​C)​ ​​* 4​ + ​(F​ ​​/ C) * 5​)
```

I tested that formula on some top users, there were users who are not very active, but they had (for example) 4 photos, and they earned more than 50,000 stars, and 14,000 copies, and had more than 40,000 followers. by the formula, their reputation was very good, but we had users who are more active, but they are not having like 50,000 stars for their photos (their photos stars are between 0 to 3,000) but they had more than 100 photos, then the formula is not fair at all!

Here is how entities are important for us:

1- (the most important) **G**  Total of copies for all photos.

2- (important) **F** Total of stars for all user's photos.

3- (Somehow important) **C** Total of uploaded photos.

4- (less important) **A and B** Number of followers and followings *(it might show if a user is a famous person or not too - but maybe it should not be very important)*

---

Can you please help me to have the formula to calculate each user value or reputation? Or is there any algorithm for such a thing?

Comment: I think 'normalizing' each of your variables would help. One way to do this would be to calculate the number of standard deviations from the mean for each of $\mathbf{G}$,$\mathbf{F}$,$\mathbf{C}$, and $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}$ and then weight them accordingly. Let $\mathbf{X}_z$ be the $z$-score of the statistic $\mathbf{X}$, and $w_{\mathbf{X}}$ its weight in the formula. Your rating could be something like $$\mathbf{G}_z w_{\mathbf{G}}+ \mathbf{F}_z w_{\mathbf{F}}+\mathbf{C}_z w_{\mathbf{C}}+\mathbf{A}_zw_{\mathbf{A}}+\mathbf{B}_zw_{\mathbf{B}}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is very open, but I'll do my best to give as many ideas as possible for you to choose from. I'm going to assume that this formula would work best if you split it up into the sum of multiple individual terms each involving the different aspects that you want to consider.

Since you think followers and followings should be important but not that important, I would use a function like
$$\frac{L}{1+(L-1)e^{-A-B}}-1$$
Where $L$ represents the largest amount of reputation that one can receive from followers or followings. This is useful because as $A+B$ increases, this always increases, but never exceeds the amount $L$, allowing you to put a cap on people who try to get all of their reputation by following people. This is also useful because if $A+B$ is $0$, so is this term. If you want to assign weights to $A$ and $B$, add coefficients in front of them.

Also, for $A$ and $B$, to discourage spam-following, you could use something like
$$e^A+e^{-A}-e^{0.1B-A}-e^{A-0.1B}$$
This function increases as $A$ increases *until* $B$, the number of followings, surpasses A, the number of followers, after which it begins the decrease slightly, discouraging spam-following for popularity.

For $F$, $C$, and $G$, you may want to use something like
$$\frac{C+F+G}{C^2}$$
which discourages users from spam-posting images (hence the $C^2$ in the denominator) but encourages the use of high-quality posts, because getting more stars and copies per picture is encouraged. You also said that you wanted to weight $G$ more than $F$. I'm not sure how much you want to do this, so I'll leave it to you - adding a coefficient in front of it might be a good idea. You could also replace it with $G^{1.1}$, which would give it a subtle boost.

You could also provide boosts to people who have fewer followers but larger ratios of stars/copies per photo (which helps talented but new users get noticed). A term like
$$\frac{G+F}{e^AC}$$
would accomplish this by increasing proportionally with the number of copies or stars per photo, but decreasing as the number of followers increases. To clarify, this doesn't *hurt* people with fewer followers, but it provides an extra bump to new users who are doing well.

If you chose a few of these and summed them, that would make a good formula.

All right, that's it. Please let me know if that was helpful. You may have to fine-tune these to add weight to certain variables or to increase or decrease the rate at which these affect your final formula, so they are by no means a final product.

Here's an example:

Let's try the formula
$$\frac{2C+3F+4G}{C^2}+\frac{5,000}{1+(4,999)e^{-A-B}}-1$$
Then user number $1$ will have a reputation of about 5000 and the second user will have about 8272.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and writing a perfect and well-written answer. I need to test these formulas on real numbers to see which one works as expected.

Comment: No problem. However, next time you may want to be a little bit more specific with your question - I think its vagueness may have scared off a few potential answerers. It was an interesting problem, though. Let me know if you need help adjusting weights.

Comment: Thanks. I will write to you about the actual problem more specifically if your current answer could not help me.

Comment: Hello again, could you please provide an example? Here is user 1 info: A=1,002, B=25, C=150, F=4,105, G=1003. Here is user 2 information: A=15,809, B=802, C=12, F=50,070, G=80,256 I tried to use your formula, but I could not find out how I could use them, an example will clarify, it would be very good if you can edit your answer and provide examples :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just had the problem in reading and understanding formulas, I think if I see math operations on reading numbers I can find out more about what's going on. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I accepted your answer. but I still did not get how to do the calculation, what is that e? Where 5,000 and 4,999 came from?

Comment: As you can see in one of my more general examples, I had let $L$ denote the largest amount of reputation that one could receive from followers and followings, and in the example, I set $L$ equal to $5000$. Also, the number $e$ is a constant (like $\pi$) often used in exponential functions. It's about $2.7$. If you want to look into it, here's a wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: I just don't know Math language! Could you please correct me? For the example you provided (and by formula) I think the formula with numbers for user 1 (the information I gave you) will be this: `((2*1002+3*4105+4*1003)/150^2)+(5000/(1+(4999)*2.7^-1002 ^-25))-1`, But it returns **`119.35323207347227`**

Comment: Perhaps there's just an order of operations error.

Comment: Hmm! I don't know. That's the way my program will calculate according to formula

Comment: I think this part contains the error: 2.7^-1002 ^-25

Comment: I changed that to this: `((2*1002+3*4105+4*1003)/150^2)+(5000/(1+(4999)*2.7^(1002-25)))-1` and still returns error! Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nch02x4L/

Comment: It should be $-1002-25$, not $1002-25$. If you look at the formula above, it says $-A-B$, not $A-B$.

Comment: (excuse my repeatable questions) Done! But still, returns something else, it returns 118,..., Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nch02x4L/1/

Comment: If I were you, I would just plug this in to an online calculator to test if it works rather than trying to type it in messily to a javascript terminal. It's easier to detect errors that way.

Comment: Thanks, but at the end point it's going to calculate via Node.js which is JavaScript! Actually, I don't know a lot about Math and that's my problem! I think I just converted your formula to JS